# Multiple cron jobs using wget

Tags: php, linux, web-services, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu server, and I want to do a wget cron job for just about every day of the week for different files.

I have gotten this to work for only one task, but anytime I try to do more it automatically overwrites the old one. I know how to set up times, and the format, etc; but I do not know how to do multiple wget cron jobs.

This is how I've been doing only one so far:

```
 echo "*/10 * * * 5 wget http://XXX.XXX.XXX/files/thursday.php" | crontab -
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: `crontab -e` will bring up the crontab in an editor

Comment: why not use "crontab -e" from the command line ?

Comment: @nachito I get this number that says 55 and when I try to enter my cron job I can't exit the editor after and it doesn't seem to save and no matter what button I press, I get this funny looking ^Z

Comment: @Dagon I get this number that says 55 and when I try to enter my cron job I can't exit the editor after and it doesn't seem to save and no matter what button I press, I get this funny looking ^Z

Comment: what's the system editor set  to ? vi at a guess

Comment: @Dagon It was I just checked and then I did "export EDITOR=nano" and now it seems like an easier text editor.... Did I do this correctly? thanks

Comment: yup, i use pico which is nano, and unless you want to use nutty vi, its a good idea.

Comment: @Dagon Perfect. Thank you. If you want to write what you just explained to me (plus before), I'll accept your answer for future users with this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best to use the command line crontab function for maintaing cron jobs

```
crontab -e
```

will bring up the editor.

The default on most *nix system is vi, which is not newbie friendly, but you can change it to nano or pico with

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

and if your on a system like mine, your logged in user may not be the best user to run cron jobs as; so you may may have to use `su` to switch users before editing the crontab file.

looking at what you are specify  doing, unless you really need to go through appache, you can just call the php file like so "php file.php" no wget needed.

```
*/10 * * * 5 php FULL_PATH/files/thursday.php  > /dev/null 2>&1
```